# D3 zoom, how to construct initial k-x-y transform (Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected transform function)

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming, transform

I am trying to initialize an `svg` transform for use in `d3` as follows: `var trans_d3 = {k:1, x:0, y:0}`. I then initialize transform attributes of `svg` elements --- in particular, circles --- through `.attr("transform", trans_d3)` and `.attr("r", d => size(d.datavar) / trans_d3.k)`.
I also initialize the transform directly on a group of elements: `svg.append("g").attr("class", "zoom_group_g").attr("transform", trans_d3)`.

Post-intialization, transforms are applied through `d3.zoom()`:

```
zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed({transform}) {
     trans_d3 = transform  
     zoom_group
      .attr("transform", trans_d3)
      .selectAll('circle')
      .filter(function(d){ return d3.select(this).attr("visibility") === 'visible' })
      .attr("r", d => (size(d.mkvalt) / trans_d3.k));
}

svg.call(zoom)
```

All is well after `trans_d3` has been re-assigned inside the zoom function. However, before then, I get:

`Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected transform function, "[object Object]".`

The error triggers no undesirable behavior or breaking of the App but for my personal understanding and to keep things clean, I would still like to get rid of it.

Upon `console.log`, I realize that `trans_d3` is initialized to `{k: 1, x: 0, y: 0}` whereas after update within the `zoomed` function, `trans_d3` reports the following format `Transform {k: 1.0139594797900293, x: -6.55066822354371, y: -3.1005166341602717}`. I suppose this is what triggers the error (i.e., the `trans_d3` object I initialize should look more like the second one).

My question is whether anyone can help me understand:

1. the structural difference between these two kinds of objects (i.e., `{k: 1, x: 0, y: 0}` and `Transform {k: 1.0139594797900293, x: -6.55066822354371, y: -3.1005166341602717}`), and
2. How to create an object of the second type (i.e., `Transform {k: 1.0139594797900293, x: -6.55066822354371, y: -3.1005166341602717}`) upon initialization.